# Razer Blade 14 2021 - LiveUSB hard reboot on startup, how do I debug this?

Tags: nvidia, live-usb, crash

How do I debug this? If I boot the LiveUSB (created as a FAT32 drive from ubuntu-21.10-desktop-amd64.iso) it reboots a few seconds past the bootloader.

If I load it in safe graphics mode I get to a low resolution desktop.

The firmware settings on the laptop do not seem to offer any way to preference or disable either the AMD integrated graphics or the mobile NVidia RTX3070.

I am happy to try customising a live image or debugging some other way.

Comment: Did you validate the ISO before writing it to a stick?

Comment: Yes, the image is fine.

Comment: Use safe graphics mode, install Ubuntu making sure to tick the option to install additional drivers, firmware, etc. If not dual-booting with Windows 11 then just disable Secure Boot (UEFI) before installing. Everything should work just fine after the installation with any of the GPUs.